# Comparing two text files on a Windows system

Tags: files, microsoft-windows, ediff

Since `ediff-files` and `ediff-buffers` result in `apply: Searching for program: no such file or directory, diff` error on windows machines.

How to compare two files using Emacs on a windows system?

Comment: By installing GetGnuWin32, you have access to a lot of gnu software (diff but alos wget, sed…). If you only care for diff, you could go with https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong: You don't have `diff` installed. Go get [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com) and try again.

Comment: @itsjeyd Cygwin is already installed on system

Comment: @fredtantini After installing GetGnuWin32 i get the same error

Comment: Is it in your path? I think the directory should at least be on the `exec-path` variable.

Comment: @Empty_Mind you need the package `diffutils` installed.

Comment: @nanny is it emacs mode, standalone binary for windows, something i have install in Cygwin or GetGnuWin32?

Comment: @Empty_Mind Sorry, I mean the Cygwin package.

Comment: Mingw on windows provides a minimal environment with Unix utile, including diff. Works like a charm; less overhead than Cygwin.

Comment: When I altered my PATH to include a /bin directory that had diff.exe in it, M-x diff started working in Emacs.

Comment: I'd never heard of GetGnuWin32 (which seems to be a useful thing: a package manager for the GnuWin32 collection), but I can confirm that installing the DiffUtils package from GnuWin32 worked for me. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @nanny said in comments, solution is having installed Cygwin with diffutils.
Here is how to do it:

1. Download Cygwin [from its homepage](https://cygwin.com/).
2. Install Cygwin with `diffutils: A GNU collection of diff utilities` package. This package can be found in `Utils` section in one of few steps of Cygwin installation.
   [image: installing Cygwin with diffutils]
3. Add Cygwin directories to the PATH windows system variable. This could be done by:
      a) adding your own CYGWIN variable, to keep the order. [image: creating CYGWIN system variable];
      b) and adding variable you just created to the system PATH variable.[image: adding CYGWIN variable to PATH system variable]

After this you are able to call `ediff-buffers`, `ediff-files` and others successfully. Which looks something like this:[image: running ediff]

Enjoy!

Answer (score 7):

If you have git for windows installed, then it is enough to add

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\
```

to your PATH, because it already ships with a diff executable and installs it in that folder.

Answer (score 3):

This may save people some time so I will answer here. If you do not wish to add the cygwin `bin` directory to your path (or any of the other ones suggested in the other answers), you can set the path of the program ediff uses by setting the variable `ediff-diff-program`. For example you could set it to `C:\cygwin\bin` (or whatever the actual path is in your case) if using cygwin. It took me some time to figure out which variable to set. Some that DID NOT work were: `ediff-custom-diff-program` and `diff-command`.

For example:

```
(setq ediff-diff-program "c:/CYGWIN64/bin/diff.exe")
```

does it.

Comment: IIRC, you can't call cygwin binaries outside of the shell, because they fail to load some libraries. I think this will only work when Emacs is run from Cygwin, which should have the `PATH` variable set correctly. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 I tested it on a Windows 10 machine with Emacs 26.1 by starting emacs from the taskbar without knowing about Cygwin... works fine. In addition, the solution adding it to the path would have the same issue you describe if it were really an issue.

Comment: I am sorry, the last part of my comment is incorrect. Adding it to the path would not have the same issue you suggest, since it would be able to find the libraries. That said, I tested the approach in the answer and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the command line installer https://scoop.sh/ you can get `diff` by typing `scoop install diffutils` in your prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to produce a diff, but just want to find the differences between the files, one way to do it is to use `M-x compare-windows` instead.

Open the two files such that you see both of them at the same time, move point to the beginning in both buffers, and run `M-x compare-windows`.  It will move point to the first place where the files differ.  This should work without any external executable.

Comment: This stops the point before first differing character in both files.