# What tool can I use to compare files by content in dired mode?

Tags: dired, files, diff

windows 10 (64 bit)

Emacs 26.1, Dired+

I need tool that can compare files by content with highlight different symbols.

Example:

[image]

As you can see I mark two files. Is it possible to compare this files in dired mode? Smt like press `C-c` and compare only mark files.

Comment: Are you looking for a tool outside Emacs or an Emacs command or library that will do this? If the former then the question is off topic here. Either way, the question is very broad - what exactly do you need from such a tool? What have you tried, and how did it not do what you want?

Comment: @Drew I'm looking library that compare files by content

Comment: Too vague. If you want useful help then it's up to you to make clear what behavior you're looking for. It's not up to those trying to help you to guess and then have you say, *"No, that's not it"*, *"`ediff` isn't comfortable enough"*, etc. You might have more luck with the kind of broad request you're making on a site like Reddit.

Comment: You've changed the question completely. Now it's about Dired. Please delete this question and post a new one for what you want. Be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing Files - GNU Emacs Manual:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comparing-Files.html

If you have no diff command installed then see this:

[Comparing two text files on a Windows system](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12864/comparing-two-text-files-on-a-windows-system?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You've changed the question to now be about using Dired.  So existing answers no longer apply.  That's not how it works on Stack Exchange.

---

Anyway, to help you out, in Dired you can use `dired-diff` to do what you want. If you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then you can also use `diredp-ediff` (bound to `=`).

Comment: ediff is not very comfortable tool for compare. Has any lib for this? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too broad - too vague. What's "not very comfortable" about `ediff`, for example? You don't specify what tool behavior you're looking for.

Comment: I updated my post